# How can I get the AMD driver running on Ubuntu 12.10 (AMD Radeon HD 7310& AMD Vision E1-1200 APU)

Tags: unity, drivers, ati

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the Lenovo S206 of my brother and already spent hours on trying to get the graphic driver to work.

No matter which solution I used, in the end Unity crashes, after the login I can see files on the desktop and also open folders and so on, but there is neither a window manager nor any sign of Unity (no panel on the top, no sidebar).

I used this [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/129200#129200) to install the driver and I also tried generating distribution-specific packages.

My Brother wants to go to France in two days, I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Can someone post the terminal command for installing the drivers? My Ubuntu is stuck in a command-line state and I'm posting this from my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issues but I finally found a way to use AMD drivers while keeping the Unity launcher working.

First in the terminal update your kernel with

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
```

Next go to the AMD website and download the 12.11 Beta drivers

Download the drivers and place the drive file (.run file) on the desktop

In the terminal run the following:

`cd /home/yourname/Desktop` (Replace yourname w/ your Ubuntu login username)

Followed by

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta11-x86.x86_64.run
```

The AMD driver/catalyst installer should open, follow the step by step and restart!

Your unity bar should work while you have the latest drivers! WOo!

Also - to remove the watermark (For AMD testing only) simply open the terminal and run

```
sudo gedit /etc/ati/signature
```

Then replace "Unsigned" with `9777c589791007f4aeef06c922ad54a2:ae59f5b9572136d99fdd36f0109d358fa643f2bd4a2644d9efbb4fe91a9f6590a145:f612f0b01f2565cd9bd834f8119b309bae11a1ed4a2661c49fdf3fad11986cc4f641f1ba1f2265909a8e34ff1699309bf211a7eb4d7662cd9f8e3faf14986d92f646f1bc`

Answer (score 2):

The new AMD 12.11 beta drivers (released 2012.10.23) work with Ubuntu 12.10. However to install them you must first install linux-headers-generic. Hence:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Slainte!

P.S. This [script](http://areyoueye.net/?p=187) will get rid of the watermark.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely try that when my brother is back!