# AMD Radeon HD6450 compatibility 13.04

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, radeon

My old graphics card hase just died. So I ordered a new MSI Radeon HD6450. What is the best way to install the AMD drivers?

Thank you.

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues but I finally found a way to use AMD drivers while keeping the Unity launcher working.

First in the terminal update your kernel with

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
```

Next go to the AMD website ([this link](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8LINBetaDriver.aspx)) and download the 13.8 Beta drivers

Download the drivers and place the drive file (.run file) on the desktop

In the terminal run the following:

`cd /home/yourname/Desktop` (Replace yourname w/ your Ubuntu login username)

Followed by

```
sudo sh the-run-file-name
```

The AMD driver/catalyst installer should open, follow the step by step and restart!

Your unity bar should work while you have the latest drivers! WOo!

Also - to remove the watermark (For AMD testing only) simply open the terminal and run

```
sudo gedit /etc/ati/signature
```

Then replace "Unsigned" with `9777c589791007f4aeef06c922ad54a2:ae59f5b9572136d99fdd36f0109d358fa643f2bd4a2644d9efbb4fe91a9f6590a145:f612f0b01f2565cd9bd834f8119b309bae11a1ed4a2661c49fdf3fad11986cc4f641f1ba1f2265909a8e34ff1699309bf211a7eb4d7662cd9f8e3faf14986d92f646f1bc`

Source: [How can I get the AMD driver running on Ubuntu 12.10 (AMD Radeon HD 7310& AMD Vision E1-1200 APU)](https://askubuntu.com/a/231330/99886) (I've edited it as per your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my VGA card works on Linux!
You may install the proprietary ATI graphics driver using this command:

> sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle

[image]

There is no doubt about your VGA's functionality under Ubuntu.